# CodeIgniter CRUD view abstraction

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a CMS using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and I'm stumped on the best way to go about handling the various CRUD views.  Given that my URL is similar to...

```
mydomain.com/admin/app/content/pages/edit
```

...where 'admin' is my controller and 'app' is my action method, I currently map segments 3, 4, and 5 to actual directories/files, like so:

```
/views
    /admin
        /content
            /pages
                list_view.php
                edit_view.php
                add_view.php
            /banners
                list_view.php
                edit_view.php
                add_view.php
```

One caveat is that I need to call different non-CRUD model methods depending on which page is being called, so my app() action method is starting to have have a nasty if..else block.  Also, each section's views are going to look different, because of different table data, so I don't see how I can avoid having a bunch of view pages. Obviously the downside of all this is that 1) I'm repeating a lot of code, and 2) if I add a new admin section I have to physically make a slew of new directories and add a new portion to the if...else block.

So my questions are:

1. How can I reduce the number of directories and view pages I'm creating?
2. Can [list_fields() or field_data()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/fields.html) methods lend itself to any automation?

One idea I had was to profile the table I'm interacting with, create a dynamic associative array that defines which fields I want to expose as well as the type of form element it should be, and then pass that off to a common view.  Thoughts? Flaws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this may not directly answer to your question, it may provide you with a basis on which to design your CRUD. I've used GroceryCRUD for quite a while now and pretty much swear by it for basic and advanced CRUD operations. It's pretty well designed and built and apart from the bespoke file structure, would appear to offer all that you're looking for.

The CRUD could easily be modified to incorporate the file/url structure you're looking for too.

See http://www.grocerycrud.com/

Comment: Great, thanks.  I actually just found GroceryCRUD about an hour ago and am starting to dive in.  I'd upvote you, but don't have enough rep yet. :)

Comment: Get some rep ;) GroceryCRUD is fantastic. Just be careful not to rely on a CRUD too much. They're all well and good in development but I often find that my applications outgrow the CRUD and I end up needing to develop it properly anyway. The later versions of Grocery are great though- loads of callbacks available and uploads etc. The 1-many and 1-1 relationships are nice too. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Just been looking through my old posts for any unanswered ones- you could accept the answer if it's correct even if you can't upvote yet by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can [extend](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) the CI_Model and use some [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) functions like getProperties() to help with your generic CRUDs.  In conjunction with CI's list_fields() like you mentioned, you could definitely create some generic pages to do so.

An example that can process form data for any object might be

```
function processForm() {
    $props = $this->self->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
    foreach ($props as $prop) :
        $prop->setValue($this,$this->input->post($prop->getName()));
    endforeach;
}
```

where

```
$this->self = new ReflectionClass($this);
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm not familiar with reflection (yet), but I'll look into it.  I'd upvote you, but don't have enough rep yet. :)

Comment: Definitely useful stuff whenever you want to get into writing re-usable code.